# How to support both argparse and optparse?

Tags: python, argparse, optparse

I have a small application that runs on fairly recent Linux distributions with Python 2.7+ but also on CentOS and Scientific Linux boxes that have not yet made the switch to Python 2.7. `optparse` is deprecated with Python 2.7 and frankly I don't want to support `optparse` anyway, which is why I developed the application with `argparse` in mind. However, `argparse` does not exist on these older distributions. Moreover, the sysadmins are rather suspicious of installing a backport of `argparse`.

Now, that should I do? Stick with `optparse`? Write yet-another-wrapper around both libraries? Convince sysadmins and users (who in most cases are just able to start the application) to install an `argparse` backport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would stick with `optparse` as long as it provides the functionality you currently need (and expect to need in future).

`optparse` works perfectly fine, it just won't be developed further. It's still available in Python 3, so even if one day you decide to move to Python 3, it will continue to work.

Comment: I wasn't really aware of the deprecation process within Python, but glad to hear that `optparse` won't disappear in the future _that_ fast.

Answer (score 3):

Provide a copy of `argparse.py` with your program, since there is no need to install the module. It is sufficient to get `argparse.py` from [pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse) and place it in some location included in `sys.path`.